# Plotly: How to alternate background grid color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I'm very new to Plotly and trying out some simple graphs. I have this simple example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
            x=[20, 14, 23],
            y=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            orientation='h'))

fig.show()
```

Which results in:
[image]

I would like to change the background grid color to alternate between two colors, let's say the default color and a darker gray color so that the bars are more visible. I was looking into the `fig.update_xaxes` function but was only able to change the colors of the lines which are white currently on the grid.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from:

> I was looking into the fig.update_xaxes function but was only able to
> change the colors of the lines which are white currently on the grid.

It sounds like you're actually asking how to change the ***background color*** for particular segments of the background along the y-axis. Particularly since you're also stating that:

> [...] so that the bars are more visible.

If that is in fact the case, then I would use shapes for sensible intervals with alternating background colors, and set the shapes to appear `"below"` (behind) the traces of the figure to get this:

[image]

And if you'd like to hide the gridlines you can just throw `xaxis=dict(showgrid=False)` into the mix:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

y = ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
x = [20, 14, 23]
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            orientation='h'))

# find step size for an interval for the number of y-values
steps = 1/len(y)

# set up where each interval ends
ends = [0 + steps*(e+1) for e in np.arange(0, len(y))]

# container for shapes to be added as backgrounds
shapes = []
# super-easy way of making a list for alternating backgrounds
colors = ['grey', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']*len(y)

# set up shapes for alternating background colors
for i, e in enumerate(ends):
        shapes.append(dict(type="rect",
                        xref="paper",
                        yref="paper",
                        x0=0,
                        y0=e-steps,
                        x1=1,
                        y1=e,
                        fillcolor=colors[i],
                        opacity=0.5,
                        layer="below",
                        line_width=0,
        )
    )
# fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=True), shapes=shapes)
# fig.show()
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showgrid=False), shapes=shapes)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this really helps! I can definitely extend this code for the other axis as well. Wish there was a native way to do this instead of shapes, but this is a good workaround

Comment: @codingenthusiast Happy to help! Let me know if you're struggling with adapting my suggestion to other purposes.